# How find this system $I_{G}=\frac{E(R_{2}R_{3}-R_{1}R_{4})}{R_{G}(R_{1}+R_{2})(R_{3}+R_{4})+R_{1}R_{2}( R_{3}+R_{4})+R_{3}R_{4}(R_{1}+R_{2})}$

Tags: calculus

let $E,R_{1},R_{2},R_{3},R_{4},R_{G},E$ is give positive numbers.and such
$$\begin{cases}
I_{1}-I_{2}-I_{G}=0\\
I_{3}+I_{G}-I_{4}=0\\
I_{2}+I_{4}-I=0\\
R_{1}I_{1}+R_{G}I_{G}-R_{3}I_{3}=0\\
R_{2}I_{2}-R_{4}I_{4}-R_{G}I_{G}=0\\
E=R_{3}I_{3}+R_{4}I_{4}
\end{cases}$$
show that
$$I_{G}=\dfrac{E(R_{2}R_{3}-R_{1}R_{4})}{R_{G}(R_{1}+R_{2})(R_{3}+R_{4})+R_{1}R_{2}(
R_{3}+R_{4})+R_{3}R_{4}(R_{1}+R_{2})}$$

This problem background is from physical,But I fell this system is very ugly,and I can't solve this equation.can you someone  can help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: The first equation is equal to what? $I_1-I_2-I_G=??$

Comment: Does this equations come from a resistor network? If that is the case, then having a graph of the network in front of you is usually a good idea. The symmetry of the graph sometimes can tell you how to arrange and hence simplify the equations.

Comment: Learn something new everyday. One can compute the current through the middle resistor $R_G$ by transforming the remaining part of a bridge circuit to its [Thevenin's equivalent circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem#Calculating_the_Th.C3.A9venin_equivalent), see [this](http://ion.chem.usu.edu/~sbialkow/Classes/564/Thevenin/Thevenin.html) for how this is done for the bridge circuit ($R_5$ there corresponds to your $R_G$, $I$ there corresponds to $I_G$).

Answer (score 1):

These equations must be related to electrical circuit and you use Kirchhoff's circuit laws to build these equations, right?

**Hint :**

I think the quickest way to solve these equations simultaneously is arranging the equations to the matrix form.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & R_1 & 0 & -R_3 & 0 & 0 & R_G\\
0 & 0 & R_2 & 0 & -R_4 & 0 & -R_G\\
0 & 0 & 0 & R_3 & R_4 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I\\
I_1\\
I_2\\
I_3\\
I_4\\
I_G\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
E\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now, let
$$
\mathbf{R}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & R_1 & 0 & -R_3 & 0 & 0 & R_G\\
0 & 0 & R_2 & 0 & -R_4 & 0 & -R_G\\
0 & 0 & 0 & R_3 & R_4 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad\mathbf{I}=\begin{bmatrix}
I\\
I_1\\
I_2\\
I_3\\
I_4\\
I_G\\
\end{bmatrix},\;\text{and}
\quad\mathbf{V}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
E\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then the equations turn out to be
$$
\mathbf{R}\mathbf{I}=\mathbf{V}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\mathbf{I}=\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{V},
$$
where $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ is the inverse of matrix $\mathbf{R}$. I leave the rest to you my friend, just one more hint: to calculate $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ a bit easier, you should consider to use column $1$.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$